# Communication between Spring Boot and Redis containers

Tags: docker, spring-boot, redis

I implemented simple, standalone webapp with REST API based on Spring Boot framework. My app is using Redis to cache some data. Now I would like to dockerize webapp and Redis cache to provide simple run procedure without forcing Redis installation in working environment.

I tried many approaches but I still struggle with `RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection` and root cause `ConnectException: Connection refused`.

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <repository>${project.artifactId}</repository>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    links:
     - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/xxx.jar abc.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS - Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /abc.jar" ]
```

application.properties:

```
spring.redis.host=redis
spring.redis.port=6379
```

I autowire `StringRedisTemplate` via constructor, get `ValueOperations` from template and simple use it (No extra Redis configuration). I run app with command `sudo docker-compose up` and get exception listed above with every Sprin Boot app call to Redis. Redis cache is reachable from host machine. Without Docker and when Redis service is installed everything is working fine.

UPDATE: I am using application.properties that I pasted before and application.yml where I store some custom configuration related to logic of my app (not framework configuration). I read that it shouldn't be a problem because Spring Boot load both files and merges them. I suspect that Redis host is not set correctly in Jedis connection but I have no idea how to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I recognized the issue. I used `sudo docker-compose up` command to start app as mentioned in question. This command rerun previously started container (doesn't rebuild image everytime), so all changes that I provided wasn't taken into consideration. I thought that project code would be recompiled.

Above configuration work fine for me. Just run `sudo docker-compose down && mvn clean install` and then `sudo docker-compose up`.

Comment: mind that it's a bad practice to use docker/docker-compose with sudo, you should configure it to be used with a regular user

Answer (score 3):

Try to create a docker network and attach the containers to this network:

`docker network create spring`

```
version: '3'
  services:
    web:
      build: .
      ports:
       - "8080:8080"
      networks:
       - spring
    redis:
      image: redis
      command: [ "redis-server", "--protected-mode", "no" ]
      ports:
        - "6379:6379"
      networks:
        - spring
  networks:
    spring:
      external: true
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I get exactly same exception.

Comment: @Geeky updated docker-compose file. Apparently there is a security mode that is enabled by default. Check protected mode section https://redis.io/topics/security

Comment: UnfortunatelyI it doesn't resolve the problem, same exception is thrown.

Comment: mind that `networks` at the end is wrongly indented (tried to edit but couldn't). It should be at the root level.